# Laravel Blade slot name undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple component with a named slot, I have used it with several other pages and it works fine, but when I call it in this one page, I get "undefined variable $headline" exceptions.

The component:

```
 <div class='widget'>
  <h1>
    {{ $headline }}
  </h1>

@if (session('message'))
  <div class="message">
    {{ session('message') }}
  </div>
@endif

  {{ $slot }}

</div>
```

The calling:

```
    {{-- components/index --}}
<x-library.page-widget>
  <x-slot:headline>
    {{ ucfirst($plural) }}
  </x-slot:headline>
  @if($conditions)
    <h3>
    @foreach($conditions as $field => $value)
    @if($loop->first)
      Where {{ $field }} is {{ $value }}
    @elseif($loop->last)
      and {{ $field }} is {{ $value }}
    @else
      , {{ $field }} is {{ $value }}
    @endif
    @endforeach
    </h3>
  @endif
  @if($favorites)
  @else
  @endif

  <div class='index-container'>
  @forelse($dataEntities as $idx => $ent)
    <x-preview 
      :size="$previewSize" 
      :route="$routeName" 
      :entity="$ent"
      :query="$queryVars" 
      :linkdataatts="[
        'return-root' => '{{ $entity }}-sub-index-{{ $idx }}'
      ]"
    />
    <div id="{{ $entity }}-sub-index-{{ $idx }}" class='sub-index-container'> </div>
  @empty
    No {{ $plural }} yet
  @endforelse
  </div>

</x-library.page-widget>
```

I've compared everything to the other contexts where I use it, and am completely stumped. This is Laravel 9.

Comment: Can you try to:   <x-slot name="headline"> instead of   <x-slot:headline>

Comment: That should work. Could you please paste the full components? Maybe there's some collision between variable names

Comment: Added the complete calling component. Thanks! I also searched my project and that is the only file in the whole project that uses a variable named $headline

Comment: I haven't used the functionality but note [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#slots) closes the slot with `</x-slot>` and omits the name. Any reason not to just use attributes?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks. I noticed that in the documentation and tried it and it did not make a difference. I also have this same component working elsewhere, which is what makes it so confusing. Not sure what you mean about using attributes. Thanks!

Comment: `<x-library.page-widget :headline="ucfirst($plural)">`

Comment: That is an interesting workaround. I will likely try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$headline` variable in your component class. It should be working.